# Warning: Could not find file C:\Users\Harsh Jain\Downloads\com.mysql.jdbc_5.1.5.jar\co

Tags: mysql, jsp

I am getting this error while running the Student Management System project in netbeans Ide project in made in java,jsp,html.Please help me

Comment: C:\Users\dell\Desktop\Student management system\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1018: Warning: Could not find file C:\Users\Harsh Jain\Downloads\com.mysql.jdbc_5.1.5.jar\com.mysql.jdbc_5.1.5.jar to copy.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
This is the error friends

Answer (score 0):

Your project's build has a dependency on the Java ARchive (.jar file) com.mysql.jdbc_5.1.5

There are two possibilities that I see here, without further details on what you have done so far:

1) You already downloaded the jar, but when you specified the path where your build process is gonna look for that file you had an error in your path ... make sure you have a jar file in C:\Users\Harsh Jain\Downloads\com.mysql.jdbc_5.1.5.jar or C:\Users\Harsh Jain\Downloads\com.mysql.jdbc_5.1.5.jar\com.mysql.jdbc_5.1.5.jar (I'm thinking you might have copied the name of the jar file twice in your path).

2) If you have not manually downloaded that file, then you should do so. You can find that version at http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcommysqljdbc515jar.htm (or elsewhere). Once downloaded, make sure to copy/unzip the actual JAR file to your C:\Users\Harsh Jain\Downloads folder.

Once you have ensured the file is actually on your system AND in the right path, run the build again.